# Accesing parent elements in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, grid, relative-path

I have a problem to reach a button which is not in the same grid as event trigger.
In one grid we have a trigger:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="BottomGrid" Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" >
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="OpenMenuButton">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuOpen}"></BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    ...
</Grid>
```

And in the second, there is a button OpenMenuButton

```xml
<Grid x:Name ="TopGrid" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF299FDD" >
    <Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid">
          <Button Name="CloseMenuButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"  Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon ArrowCollapseRight}" ToolTip="Icon" Click="ButtonCloseMenu_Click"/>
          <Button Name="OpenMenuButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"  Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon Menu}" ToolTip="Icon" Visibility="Collapsed"  Click="ButtonOpenMenu_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    ...
</Grid>
```

But there is a problem, that the EvenTrigger cannot find OpenMenuButton, because is somewhere else in the tree. Something like TopGrid.ButtonGrid.OpenMenuButton didnt work. What is the right relative path and its syntax?

Comment: documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventtrigger.sourcename?view=net-5.0) says: You can set this property to the name of any element within the scope of where the trigger collection (the collection that this EventTrigger is part of) is applied. This is typically a named element that is within the template that contains this EventTrigger. If you are setting the Triggers property on an element directly, then it is a named element within the scope of that parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to change the `boolean` value.
Also set `toryboard.TargetName = "MyMenu"` to the name of the menu you want to control with the click event and also `Storyboard.TargetProperty = "IsSubmenuOpen"` for the menu opening feature.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="OpenMenuButton">
      <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
        <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSubmenuOpen" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Width="44" Height="34" Name="OpenMenuButton" Foreground="Black" Background="Red" Margin="8, 0, 0, 0" Content="Open Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    </Button>

    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="MyMenu">
      <MenuItem Header="_New" />
      <MenuItem Header="_Open" />
      <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
      <Separator />
      <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Or if you want to open and close the menu from the line below inside the `Storyboard` And change the `button` to `ToggleButton`.

```
 <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value = "{Binding Path = IsChecked, ElementName = OpenMenuButton}" KeyTime = "0: 0: 1" />
       Use the BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

fullcode

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="OpenMenuButton">
      <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
        <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="mymnu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSubmenuOpen" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="{Binding  Path=IsChecked,ElementName=OpenMenuButton}" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
  <StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Width="44" Height="34" Name="OpenMenuButton" Foreground="Black" Background="Red" Margin="8, 0, 0, 0" Content="click" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    </ToggleButton>

    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="mymnu">
      <MenuItem Header="_New" />
      <MenuItem Header="_Open" />
      <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
      <Separator />
      <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```